# Lua: relative import fails from different working directory

Tags: lua

I'm trying to repackage into a Docker container some Lua library that is made of the main module and some helper modules. The helper modules are kept inside a subfolder of the library so that imports from the main file are done as

```
require 'helpers/SomeHelper'
```

The problem is: because of the way I want the Docker container to work, it would be extremely helpful if I can invoke this library from a different working folder. That is, my call to the main program would be something like

```
th /app/main.lua
```

regardless of the actual working directory I'm standing. Unfortunately, relative imports seem to fail when the working directory is different from the directory where the main file is located.

Is there any way I can configure LUA_PATH or any other mechanism to make these imports work correctly? Note that changing the code of the library itself would be a poor solution, as it wasn't developed by me and I would like to be able to update it to newer versions easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care about the working directory, you can just load [`lfs` / LuaFileSytem](https://keplerproject.github.io/luafilesystem/) and use [`lfs.chdir`](https://keplerproject.github.io/luafilesystem/manual.html#chdir)`( src_dir )` to change to the source directory (potentially saving the current working directory with [`lfs.currentdir`](https://keplerproject.github.io/luafilesystem/manual.html#currentdir)`( )` first.)

You can also extend the [search path](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-package.path) of Lua so that it will search those extra directories.  The search is driven by [`package.searchpath`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-package.searchpath).  To add a directory `/foo/bar/` to the search in a way that supports all normally supported library layouts, add

- `/foo/bar/?.lua;/foo/bar/?/init.lua` to `package.path`
- `/foo/bar/?.so` (or `.dylib` or `.dll` on other OSen) to `package.cpath`

You can use several ways to extend the path.

One option that works well is to set the `LUA_PATH` / `LUA_CPATH` environment variables.  (A `;;` sequence in one of them will expand to the full default path.)  This can be done from `.profile` or other setup scripts via an earlier `export LUA_PATH="..."` or (if started from a wrapper script) inline by setting variables just for that call `LUA_PATH="..." lua /foo/bar.lua`.  (Note that if you export this variable in too broad a scope, other Lua scripts will also get their path extended and may find potentially incompatible Lua libraries.)

(You can also manually modify `package.(c)path` from `LUA_INIT`.  That way, you won't be able to independently disable `LUA_INIT` or `LUA_PATH`, but you can use all of Lua to generate the path dynamically.)

A third option (this may be best in your specific case) is to put the extension of `package.path` at the top of your main script, as in

```
do
   local dir = (arg[0]:match "^(.*)/$")
   if dir then -- else cwd is . which works by default
      package.path = dir.."/?.lua;"..dir.."/?/init.lua;"..package.path
      package.cpath = dir.."/?.so;"..package.cpath
   end
end

-- rest of your program goes here
```

When running a script with the Lua interpreter, `arg[0]` is the script.  So this extends the path to include the program's directory no matter where it is located, and it will only affect the search path of this particular script / program.

Comment: Very complete answer! Since I'm packaging the application inside a Docker container and don't want to modify its code, the option that worked best for me was to change the LUA_PATH environment variable. I just had to declare LUA_PATH="/app/?.lua;/app/helpers/?.lua;;" to make the require operations work.

Answer (score 0):

You should not forget about that not all modules are loaded from FS directly.
E.g. to improve perfomance it is possible read/compile file to memory and then
use preload table to provide way to load module from memory. 
Basic example

```
--- preload code. It can be done by host application.
local FooUtils = function()
  return {
    print = function(...)
      print("foo", ...)
    end
  }
end

local Foo = function()
  local Utils = require "foo.utils"
  return {
    foo = function()
      Utils.print"hello"
    end
  }
end

package.preload['foo.utils'] = FooUtils
package.preload['foo'] = Foo

--- main application
require "foo".foo()
```

In this example assume that `FooUtils` and `Foo` just example of compiled modules.
E.g. it can be like `FooUtils = loadstring('path/to/utils.lua)` and it can be done
even in separate Lua state and then used in any other.
It is important to remember that `Foo` module have no idea about how host application does lookup of `foo.utils`.
So there no standart way to provide original file path or relevant paths.
So if you write some module wich relays on relative paths then this module
may be not working in some environments.
So I just suggest use full namespace like `require 'foo.utils'` instead of `require 'utils'`

Comment: I don't get how this should help with this particular problem. In particular, how does this solve the _"Note that changing the code of the library itself would be a poor solution, as it wasn't developed by me and I would like to be able to update it to newer versions easily."_ part? (The `require "foo.bar"` _inside_ the libraries used is part of the problem.)

Comment: I just say do not use relative paths because lua does not support it quite well. It is possible add `/app/?.lua` to LUA_PATH. But it should be done not to system wide but only for this particular script. E.g. via some startup script